# disable double tap zoom WebView for titanium mobile development

Tags: android, webview, titanium

The titanium app for Android shows a zoom when we double tap the screen. How can I disable this feature from my own Webview in titanium?

```
var mywebview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
        enableZoomControls : 'false',
        keepScreenOn : 'true',
        scalesPageToFit : 'true',
        top : '0%',
        left : '0%',
        right : '0%',
        url : fbUrl,
        width : '100%'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: gets error if i use it. getSettings() function is not avalible for webview in "Titanium Studio, build: 3.2.1.201402041146" for android build

Comment: @maheshrocks It Works in android. See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Comment: sorry i am using titanium.webview not android webview

Comment: @maheshrocks see whether there is setZoomControls or disablezoom property on your titanium webview. see this link : - https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/commit/54854ce33ddf68477fd3632cf4d63b565e0c8e65#diff-1

Comment: disablezoom property is only removing the icons of zoomin/zoomout but not disabling double tap

Comment: we are using http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView